# SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH in chrome 42

Tags: tls, chrome

My [ssl-enabled site](http://tracer-db.arcs.co) has stopped working in Chrome 42. It still works in Chrome 41.

[Qualys's test](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=tracer-db.arcs.co) doesn't cover Chrome 42, but it also doesn't raise any issues that indicate it's about to stop working, either.

Has Chrome 42 dropped support for the previously negotiated cipher suite (`TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0xc02b)`)?

Comment: https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/viewMyClient.html may be helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comparing [client capabilities](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/viewMyClient.html) I have noted that Chrome 42  only supports the following elliptic curves:

> Elliptic curves:  secp256r1,  secp384r1

(It appears that secp521r1 used to be supported in earlier versions, there is a [bug report for this](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=478225).)

While for instance Firefox 37 supports:

> Elliptic curves   secp256r1, secp384r1, secp521r1

Looking at the results for the [SSLLabs test of your site](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=tracer-db.arcs.co), it appears that you are using a 521 bit curve.

> Key:  EC 521 bits

Answer (score 0):

I hit this issue recently. From what I can tell the removal of support for secp521r1 was intentional: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=477623 and there are no plans to bring it back. The intent was to support 25519-curve server keys instead.

In our case we simply switched to a different server key.